# How to solve third party library dependency version conflict issues in Android?

Tags: android

After adding third party library dependency `'com.karumi:dexter:5.0.0'` to show run time permissions in app started facing this version conflict issue.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:5.0.0'
```

[image]

Is there any better solution for this problem to avoid run time crashes in my future apps?

Answer (score 0):

You should change,

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

(or)

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design: 28.0.0'
```

try to maintain same version for all dependency.

Comment: yeah this solved my problem and also i found that adding highest dependency version also solves these kind of problems.

Comment: If it is useful to you, make it right answer.

Comment: since i m new i have less reputation..I tried to vote up but it's saying can't ..

Comment: Okay @user3357003

Answer (score -1):

You should try app compact implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'